# Bash: Slow redirection and filter

Tags: bash, logging, filtering, redirect, pipe

I have a bash script that calls a program which generates a humongous amount of output. A lot of this data is coming from a Python package that I have not created and whose output I can't really control, nor interests me.

I tried to filter the output generated by that external Python package and redirect the "cleaned" output to a log file. If I used regular pipes and grep expressions, I lost many chunks of information. I read that is something that can actually happen with the redirections ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/bash-script-read-values-from-stdin-pipe) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290684/using-named-pipes-with-bash-problem-with-data-loss)).

In order to fix that, I made the redirections like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
regexTxnFilterer="\[txn\.-[[:digit:]]+\]"
regexThreadPoolFilterer="\[paste\.httpserver\.ThreadPool\]"
bin/paster serve --reload --pid-file="/var/run/myServer//server.pid"  parts/etc/debug.ini 2>&1 < "/dev/null" | while IFS='' read -r thingy ; do
        if [[ ! "$thingy" =~ $regexTxnFilterer ]] && [[ ! "$thingy" =~ $regexThreadPoolFilterer ]]; then
                  echo "$thingy" >> "/var/log/myOutput.log" 
        fi
done
```

Which doesn't lose any information (at least not that I could tell) and filters the strings I don't need (using the two regular expressions above).

The issue is that it has rendered the application (the `bin/paster` thing I'm executing) unbearably slow. Is there any way to achieve the same effect but with a better performance?

Thank you in advance!

**Update @2012-04-13**: As [shellter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) pointed out in one of the comments to this question, it may be useful to provide examples of the outputs I want to filter. Here's a bunch of them:

```
2012-04-13 19:30:37,996 DEBUG [txn.-1220917568] new transaction
2012-04-13 19:30:37,997 DEBUG [txn.-1220917568] commit <zope.sqlalchemy.datamanager.SessionDataManager object at 0xbf4062c>
2012-04-13 19:30:37,997 DEBUG [txn.-1220917568] commit
Starting server in PID 18262.
2012-04-13 19:30:38,292 DEBUG [paste.httpserver.ThreadPool] Started new worker -1269716112: Initial worker pool
2012-04-13 19:33:08,158 DEBUG [txn.-1244144784] new transaction
2012-04-13 19:33:08,158 DEBUG [txn.-1244144784] commit
2012-04-13 19:32:06,980 DEBUG [paste.httpserver.ThreadPool] Added task (0 tasks queued)
2012-04-13 19:32:06,980 INFO [paste.httpserver.ThreadPool] kill_hung_threads status: 10 threads (0 working, 10 idle, 0 starting) ave time N/A, max time 0.00sec, killed 0 workers
```

There's a few more different messages involving the ThreadPool though, but I couldn't catch any.

Comment: consider updating your question to include some sample values for $thingy that you want to skip. I'm guessing there is a more efficient reg-ex that can be applied to your case. Also, consider using `sed` as your filter instead of the `while read thingy` loop. Good luck.

Comment: Hmm. more complicated than I expected. Can you reedit and add a final block of example output required, given the ~10 lines you have posted. Is 'Starting server ...' really on it's own seperate line? Good luck.

Comment: oh, one other thing you can do right away to speed up your regular expression, is assuming that your logfile 'header' is always like '2012-04-13 19:30:37,996 DEBUG ', is to anchor the reg ex to the front of the line, and indicate any 30 chars, i.e. `/^.\{30\}\[txn\.-[[:digit:]]+\]`. You may need to experiment, maybe it is really `/^.{30}/` (without the escaping '\' chars in front of {}. OR worst case `/^..............................\[txn\.-[[:digit:]]+\]/.`. I still think `sed` is a better tool for this. for your INFO line, recall that `.?` means zero or one of the preceing char. Good luck.

Comment: Using a shell script for this is silly -- there's a filtering mechanism built straight into the Python logging mechanism, so you can simply tell it you don't want `DEBUG` messages for those classes to start with.

Comment: ...when you say "don't really control", does that mean you also can't edit the `parts/etc/debug.ini` file (or make your own version of that file)? Having config files configurable by sysadmin staff rather than developers is part of the whole point of _having_ them separate from code.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: What you're proposing is the right way of doing things which I was already aware of, but: As you probably already know, the parts/etc/debug.ini is just used in developer mode and pretty much generated with default values on a buildout. I'd like to keep those default values. The "real" servers are not going to be run in debug mode, and they're not going to show DEBUG messages. I launch my server through an script and I want a quick way of filtering messages without altering the debug.ini.in file.

Comment: @BorrajaX ...you could have your script append to the stock debug.ini file and invoke against the modified version. This would be best-of-both-worlds -- no manual reconfiguration needed, updates to upstream debug.ini take effect on restart, and no shell script filtering causing writes to block and cutting into performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be faster to use a grep-based solution to this

```
#!/bin/bash
regexTxnFilterer="\[txn\.-[[:digit:]]+\]"
regexThreadPoolFilterer="\[paste\.httpserver\.ThreadPool\]"
bin/paster serve --reload --pid-file="/var/run/myServer//server.pid"  parts/etc/debug.ini 2>&1 < "/dev/null" | grep -vf <(echo "$regexTxnFilterer"; echo "$regexThreadPoolFilterer") >> "/var/log/myOutput.log"
```

Your loop may be slow because the `echo "$thingy" >> "/var/log/myOutput.log"` line is opening and closing the log file every time it executes. I wouldn't expect there to be a big performance difference between grep's regex matching and bash's, but if there was it wouldn't surprise me.

---

**Late Edit**

There's a far simpler way to fix the performance issue caused by opening/closing the output once per line. Why this didn't occur to me before, I have no idea. Just move the `>>` to outside your loop

```
#!/bin/bash
regexTxnFilterer="\[txn\.-[[:digit:]]+\]"
regexThreadPoolFilterer="\[paste\.httpserver\.ThreadPool\]"
bin/paster serve --reload --pid-file="/var/run/myServer//server.pid"  parts/etc/debug.ini 2>&1 < "/dev/null" | while IFS='' read -r thingy ; do
        if [[ ! "$thingy" =~ $regexTxnFilterer ]] && [[ ! "$thingy" =~ $regexThreadPoolFilterer ]]; then
                  echo "$thingy"
        fi
done  >> "/var/log/myOutput.log"
```

I can't see any compelling reason why this would be either faster or slower than the `grep` solution, but it's a lot closer to the original code and a little less cryptic.

Comment: This seems to be working a bit better... my only concern is that when I tried "regular" redirections, I lost lines... That's why the output is "wrapped" in the while/done block. I'll keep an eye on it an will see if it's working fine.

Comment: @BorrajaX ok, well I hope it works.. I can't think why it'd be any different unless. Taking a second look at it, there's a _much_ simpler change to your code that will fix the open/close issue. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @BorrajaX edited. I'd be interested to know how the two solutions above perform for you, compared to each other

Comment: Thanks for the help: Here's the performance I found using Firefox (with all the cacheable resources cached): 0) The way I initially had --> Loading of the index page, 7.53sec; Loading of test page, 6.95sec. 1) First solution (grep) --> Index page, 5.97 sec; --> Test page, 6.47 2) Second solution (move >> oustide loop) --> Index page, 6.27; Test page: 6.38sec That's weird... I repeated the tests a bunch of times, just to make sure I'd done it properly but the times seem to be pretty much around those numbers.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing -- you're reopening the log file every time you want to append a line. That's silly.

Instead of this:

```
while ...; do
   echo "foo" >>filename
done
```

Do this (which opens the output file on a new, non-stdout file handle, such that you still have a clear line to stdout should you wish to write to it):

```
exec 4>>filename
while ...; do
   echo "foo" >&4
done
```

It's also possible to redirect stdout for the whole loop:

```
while ...; do
   echo "foo"
done >filename
```

...notably, this will impact more than just the "echo" line, and thus have slightly different semantics from the original.

---

Or, better yet -- Configure [the Python logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) to filter output to only what you care about, and don't bother with shell-script postprocessing at all.

If the version of Paste you're using is sufficiently similar to modern Pyramid, you can put this in your ini file (currently `parts/etc/debug.ini`):

```
[logger_paste.httpserver.ThreadPool]
level = INFO

[logger_txn]
level = INFO
```

...and anything below `INFO` level (including the `DEBUG` messages) will be excluded.

Comment: Even if I try to setup the level for the ThreadPool and the logger_txn in my parts/etc/debug.ini file, the log file is still showing the unwanted messages.

Comment: @BorrajaX I'd have to see the file in full (or at least the logging-related bits) to debug that -- frankly, it's probably material for a different question (one not tagged `bash`). And again, what I gave here is for Pyramid, not tested against any other Paste-based framework.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm using grok (which has Zope underneath). Thanks for the hints, though.