# Unix recursive find / replaced based on dynamic pattern?

Tags: php, unix, refactoring, replace

So, I inherited some really bad code and am currently just trying to refactor it to the point of functionality before completely overhauling it.  One of the problems is that the original programmer set posts and sessions like this:

```
$_SESSION[somename]  
$_POST[somevar]
```

instead of:

```
$_SESSION['somename']
$_POST['somevar']
```

It seems to be causing problems throughout the site.  Is there a fast way that I can recursively find and replace these types of variables? I'm using a unix box, so not sure if there's a way to do that from the command line or if I should write a php script? They're everywhere and obviously are named different, so I would need to find any variable that does not have the quotes and replace it with the same string that does?

Comment: I would do that automatically. It may cause more problems, than non-quote-enclosed-strings

Comment: Well, yes.  I agree, that's what I want to do. I just don't want to have to go through the hundred different scripts (they also used no classes, objects, or even reusable functions).  My question is, is there way to find and replace based from the command line.

Comment: I would go with just turning on logs and iteratively fixing warnings from there

Comment: What you want may be something along the lines of `find ./myphpdir -name \*.php -exec sed --in-place=.bak -e 's/$_POST(\(something\))/$_POST("\1")/'` I'm not making this an answer because the `something` is non-trivial and I'm not prepared to go into that right now.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145984/bash-slow-redirection-and-filter#comment13043109_1014598 . Especially my comment under original question ;-) The O.P. has a problem very similar to your's. There are other posts too about this technique, but I couldn't find them. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use sed for the job. I would then search for $_POST[(something)] and replace with $_POST["(something)]. Remember to go as unambiguous as you can. Also, remember to take a backup before trying to mess with it. Afterwards I would try running all the php files with "php [file]" to check if they are at least syntactically correct.